# Using Jinja for html display

Tags: python, html, jinja2

I have been finding a lot of information about *how* to write Jinja code and have 2 .py files `page1.py` and `page2.py` which reference `.jinja` files in the `templates` directory. When I run `python page1.py` I accurately get the webpage I want. In fact, when I run `python page1.py > page1.html` and then navigate to `myWebpage/page1.html`, it works perfectly.

I'm wondering, however, if jinja is supposed to (or can) run that automatically as soon as I enter `myWebpage/page1.html` into my browser. The thing is, I am using Jinja to automatically update the page as soon as parameters on the backend change. Do I need to run this python code using `cron` or is it supposed to generate the new `.html` code as soon as a user refreshes the webpage?

Below are the contents of my python and jinja pages:

(1) contents of /var/www/html/page1.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

### taken from http://kagerato.net/articles/software/libraries/jinja-quickstart.html
# Load the jinja library's namespace into the current module.
import jinja2

# In this case, we will load templates off the filesystem.
# This means we must construct a FileSystemLoader object.
# 
# The search path can be used to make finding templates by
#   relative paths much easier.  In this case, we are using
#   absolute paths and thus set it to the filesystem root.
templateLoader = jinja2.FileSystemLoader( searchpath="/usage_statistics/webfront" )

# An environment provides the data necessary to read and
#   parse our templates.  We pass in the loader object here.
templateEnv = jinja2.Environment( loader=templateLoader )

# This constant string specifies the template file we will use.
TEMPLATE_FILE = "templates/page1.jinja"

# Read the template file using the environment object.
# This also constructs our Template object.
template = templateEnv.get_template( TEMPLATE_FILE )

# Specify any input variables to the template as a dictionary.
templateVars = { "title" : "Test Example",
                 "description" : "A simple inquiry of function." }

# Finally, process the template to produce our final text.
outputText = template.render( templateVars )

print outputText
```

(2) contents of /var/www/html/templates/page1.jinja

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />

  <title>{{ title }}</title>
  <meta name="description" content="{{ description }}" />
</head>

<body>

<div id="content">
  <p>Why, hello there!</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

(3) contents of /var/www/html/page2.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import jinja2

templateLoader = jinja2.FileSystemLoader( searchpath="/usage_statistics/webfront" )
env = jinja2.Environment( loader=templateLoader )

TEMPLATE_FILE = "templates/page2.jinja"
template = env.get_template( TEMPLATE_FILE )

# Here we add a new input variable containing a list.
# Its contents will be expanded in the HTML as a unordered list.
FAVORITES = [ "chocolates", "lunar eclipses", "rabbits" ]

templateVars = { "title" : "Test Example",
                 "description" : "A simple inquiry of function.",
                 "favorites" : FAVORITES
               }   

#outputText = template.render( templateVars )
#template.render( templateVars )
print template.render( templateVars )
```

(4) contents of page2.jinja

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />

  <title>{{ title }}</title>
  <meta name="description" content="{{ description }}" />
</head>

<body>

<div id="content">
  <p>Greetings visitor!  These are a list of my favorite things:</p>

  <ul>
  {% for item in favorites %}
    <li>{{ item }}</li>
  {% endfor %}
  </ul>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I might have misunderstood your question, but it sounds to me more like you need to use a web framework like Flask to handle the request, this will then render the jinja2 template when it is requested. I *think* this is what you want? You can still use your templates but you'll need to handle the request and return the template view with Flask. See http://flask.pocoo.org/

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, this might not be what I'm looking for. I can run the python script but it says ` * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/` and I'm hoping to view this from something other than localhost.